# Problem with missing values in Altair or Plotly choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, altair, choropleth

I have data for a few states in the US and others are Null. While creating the maps,  I would like to shade in the states with the missing value in the text but I am struggling to find the correct method. With my current code, I am unable to get the entire US map including the states with the Null value, and only the states with a certain assigned value pop up. I have also looked at previous questions posted and tried layering the maps but that gives me an error.
[here's how cc_df looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTRI4.png)

Here's my code:

```py
# import the required library
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt# import seaborn library
%matplotlib inline
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# State database
states_df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt',
# pipe seperated file
sep="|",
# FIPS are best as strings
dtype='str',
# rename columns
header=0, names=['state_fips', 'state', 'state_name', 'StateENS'],
# drop last column
usecols=['state_fips', 'state_name', 'state']
).set_index('state')
states_df['id'] = states_df['state_fips'].astype(int)

# The data to map
cc_df = pd.read_csv('hv_cwad.csv',
                    usecols=['state', 'CWAD'])
cc_df = cc_df.groupby('state').mean()

# Combine state database and our own data
#cc_state_df = pd.merge(cc_df, states_df)
cc_state_df = states_df.join(cc_df).reset_index()

# %%
# Create the map
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
variable_list = ['CWAD']

alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(stroke='lightgrey',
                                strokeWidth=.5).encode(
    alt.Color(alt.repeat('row'), type='quantitative')
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(cc_state_df, 'id', variable_list)
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=300
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).repeat(
    row=variable_list
).resolve_scale(
    color='independent'
)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: output with the current code]

Comment: I also tried layering two maps. This is how the code looks like for that 

  
 #Adding an outline to the map
    outline = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape( stroke='black').project(
        type='albersUsa'
    ).properties(
        #width=700,
        #height=400
    )
    
    alt.layer(plot,outline)

But this gives me a ValueError: Repeat charts cannot be layered

Comment: I think you can repeat a layered chart (other way around). I tried to copy+paste your code, but I got a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hv_cwad.csv`.

Comment: Mattjin, I have added a snapshot of the data frame (cc_df). I don't think we can add the csv file here. Could you please clarify what you mean by "other way"?

Comment: I ran your code and confirmed that the NA states are not displayed. When I updated the missing data value to 0, all states were displayed. I will respond if this is what you want.

Comment: @r-beginners Yes, please. Thank you. As you can see in the output plot, it looks odd with just the states with data. I was attempting to add the states with no data in grey or at least an outline of the states with missing data.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for your efforts. I modified the code and replaced the missing states with 0 in place of NA. The problem with that is that some of the states have a CWAD value of 100 or less. So the missing data states look like they have low CWAD value rather than no data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was aware that the points you pointed out were issues, so I did some research against NaN values and found the [following answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229651/dealing-with-missing-values-nulls-in-altair-choropleth-map). However, the conditional judgment of the null value did not work, so I replaced the missing value with -1 to get the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# State database
states_df = pd.read_csv('https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt', 
                        sep="|", 
                        dtype='str', 
                        header=0, 
                        names=['state_fips', 'state', 'state_name', 'StateENS'],
                        usecols=['state_fips', 'state_name', 'state']).set_index('state')

states_df['id'] = states_df['state_fips'].astype(int)

import io

data = '''
state CWAD
AR 377.715148
FL 6560.929494
GA 1958.122132
IA 0.409179
KS 63.706671 
'''

cc_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
# The data to map
#cc_df = pd.read_csv('hv_cwad.csv', usecols=['state', 'CWAD'])
cc_df = cc_df.groupby('state').mean()

# Combine state database and our own data
#cc_state_df = pd.merge(cc_df, states_df)
cc_state_df = states_df.join(cc_df).reset_index()
cc_state_df.fillna(-1, inplace=True)

# Create the map
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')

variable_list = ['CWAD']

alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='lightgrey',
    strokeWidth=.5
).encode(
        color=alt.condition('datum.CWAD !== -1', 'CWAD:Q', alt.value('lightgray'))
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(
        cc_state_df,
        'id',
        variable_list)
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=300
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).repeat(
    row=variable_list
).resolve_scale(
    color='independent'
)
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I modified the code and replaced the missing states with 0 in place of NA. The problem with that is that some of the states have a CWAD value of 100 or less. So the missing data states look like they have low CWAD value rather than no data at all.

Comment: Thank you. That definitely is a good workaround. I tried your solution and it works for this particular dataset since all my data has positive values. Looks like we have two solutions now: #Altair and plotly :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to plot the missing data using Plotly instead of Altair. In case, you are not particular about using Altair, this may be helpful.

> ## import the required library

import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

```
# State database
states_df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt',
# pipe seperated file
sep="|",
# FIPS are best as strings
dtype='str',
# rename columns
header=0, names=['state_fips', 'state', 'state_name', 'StateENS'],
# drop last column
usecols=['state_fips', 'state_name', 'state']
).set_index('state')
states_df['id'] = states_df['state_fips'].astype(int)

# The data to map
cc_df = pd.read_csv('cwad_hv.csv',
                    usecols=['state', 'GWAD'])
cc_df = cc_df.groupby('state').mean()

# Combine state database and our own data
#cc_state_df = pd.merge(cc_df, states_df) #don't use this. 
cc_state_df = states_df.join(cc_df).reset_index()
#cc_state_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)#This changes the states with no data from NA to zero. If your data has a range -ve to +ve, skip this.

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=cc_state_df['state'],
    z=cc_state_df['CWAD'].astype(float),
    locationmode='USA-states',
    #color='Greens',
    autocolorscale=True,
    #range_color=[0, 6500],
    #text=df['text'], # hover text
    marker_line_color='black', # line markers between states
    colorbar_title="CWAD kg/ha"
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='CWAD',
    geo = dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=go.layout.geo.Projection(type = 'albers usa'),
        showlakes=False, # lakes
        lakecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)'),
)

fig.show()
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1mSN.png)