# Trying to set Altair color to white at zero value

Tags: altair

I'm trying to create an Altair heat map where the color is white when my count is zero.

Here is my data frame:

```
df11 = pd.DataFrame({
    'lineid': [0,1,2,0,1,2],
    'term': ['data', 'data', 'data', 'explore', 'explore', 'explore'],
    'count': [3,2,1,1,0,2],
    'title': ['weather', 'weather','weather','weather','weather','weather',]
})
alt.Chart(d11).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('lineid:O', title=None, axis=alt.Axis(ticks=False, labels=False)),
    y=alt.Y('term:O', title=None),
    color=alt.Color('count:O', legend=None)
)
```

The encoding gives me this chart (which is what I intended) but I'm trying to get the zero count (2nd row, 2nd column) to be white not light blue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional encoding as in [How to make Altair display NaN points with a quantitative color scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059639/how-to-make-altair-display-nan-points-with-a-quantitative-color-scale)

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lineid': [0,1,2,0,1,2],
    'term': ['data', 'data', 'data', 'explore', 'explore', 'explore'],
    'count': [3,2,1,1,0,2],
    'title': ['weather', 'weather','weather','weather','weather','weather',]
})
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('lineid:O', title=None, axis=alt.Axis(ticks=False, labels=False)),
    y=alt.Y('term:O', title=None),
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.count == 0, alt.value('white'), 'count:O', legend=None)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  I forgot about alt.condition()